# How to transform a 5x5 block into a diagonal box in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have the code:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){ 
 for (int j = 0 ; j < 5; j++) System.out.print("*"); 
 System.out.println();}
```

which gives:

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

How do I transform it into:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to loop to `5 - i` times in inner loop

Comment: I may sound like an idiot but I don't quite know what that means... as in, what does 5 - i "times" mean?

Comment: 5, then 4, then 3, then 2, then 1

Comment: I guess one less on each row?

Comment: that is what you want

Comment: Sorry dude!! did not mean to downvote. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Don't be scared of testing and experimenting different results.

**Updated:**

OK. I just tested things here and tried this code in Obj-C and it did print exactly what you want:

```
int i,j;
for(i=5; i>=1; i--)
{
    for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The Java translation for that would be:

```
for(int i=5; i>=1; i--)
{ 
    for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
        System.out.print("*"); 
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I've tried that several times and it's not producing any result. My compiler is acting kind of funny, going real slow. I am going to try and exit and restart

Comment: I updated the answer. Check it out. It must work. Also these two lecture files can be helpful:
http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse142/09sp/lectures/lec4.pdf
and 
http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse142/09sp/lectures/lec5.pdf
Always remember to search well before asking a new question. (:

Answer (score -1):

The following code will fix your problem

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++)
    { 
        for (int j = 5-i ; j <= 5; j++) 
             System.out.print("*"); 
             System.out.println();

    }
```